# How to filter records with existing function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have function as follows (my function is more complex but assume this is the function):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION A(id integer)
  RETURNS a_type AS
$BODY$
declare
    a_type ROW;     
begin
    FOR ROW IN
                    select * from table_1 where x_id=id;
    LOOP
            return next row;
    end loop;
    return;
end;    
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

I want to change the function to recive 2 parmeters. the 2nd one is a number which tells how many months to go back from today:

I can change the function to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION A(id integer, months integer)
  RETURNS a_type AS
$BODY$
declare
    a_type ROW;     
begin
           if months>0 then:
    FOR ROW IN
            select * from table_1 where x_id=id and date >  CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months';
    LOOP
            return next row;
    end loop;
    return;
else:
    FOR ROW IN
            select * from table_1;
    LOOP
            return next row;
    end loop;
    return;
end;
end;    
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

However this solution forces me to write the whole query with loop twice.

Is there a way to do that without writing the same code twice?

Comment: The function is needlessly complex. A simple `return query select * from table_1 where x_id=id;` would do. There is no need for the (slow and inefficient) loop you are using.

Comment: this is not my real query.. it's just for the example. my real query is 38 rows. I just need to know how to add more condition to the WHERE in case the 2nd paremeter has value>0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
create or replace function a(p_id integer, p_months integer)
  returns setof table_1
as
$$
  select *
  from table_1
  where x_id = p_id
   and (   coalesce(p_months,0) <= 0 or 
           some_date > current_date - interval '1' month * p_months );
$$
language sql;
```

If `p_months` is passed as `null` or `0` then the first part of the `or` will be true and the other condition will not be evaluated (it will probably, because SQL does no short-circuiting, but it won't matter). If `p_months` is passed as something different, the first part of the `or` will be false and thus the second part needs to be true in order to return the correct result.

---

Note that I also changed the function from a PL/pgSQL function to a plain SQL function. There is no need to do a slow and inefficient row-by-row processing in a loop here (unless you obfuscated your code so much that you left out the part where you actually *do* something in that loop)